# Regular Expressions VBScript using the OR Expression (|)

Tags: regex, vbscript

I need to use regular expressions to parse a string.

Most times, the string can be parsed using the expression

```
^([a-zA-Z\-\,0-9\(\)\#\/ \.]{1,21})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})
```

Sometimes, the string needs to include an additional 4 characters so the expression would be

```
^([a-zA-Z\-\,0-9\(\)\#\/ \.]{1,25})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})
```

By themselves either expression would work on their respective strings.  The first will also be technically valid on a string intended for the second expression, however the .{0,9} section of the expression would be off by 4 characters.

```
A quick explanation of the expression:
Subset 1: 1 - 21 (or 25 characters)
any characters a-z
any characters A-Z
the dash, the comma
any digits 0-9
the open and close parenthesis, the hash tag, forward slash, space and period.

Subsets 2-7
Any characters (up to 9 total)
```

I was hoping for something like the expression below

```
^([a-zA-Z\-\,0-9\(\)\#\/ \.]{1,21|25})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})
```

OR

```
^([a-zA-Z\-\,0-9\(\)\#\/ \.]{1,21}|{1,25})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})
```

I tried these and they didn't work.  Anyone else got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's rather verbose, but I think you'd have to do this:

```
^([a-zA-Z\-\,0-9\(\)\#\/ \.]{1,21}|[a-zA-Z\-\,0-9\(\)\#\/ \.]{25})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})(.{0,9})
```

The first capture group must be either 1-21 characters, or 25 characters long.

If you're willing to change how your groups are captured (and if your regex engine supports it), you might also be able to do this:

```
^([a-zA-Z\-\,0-9\(\)\#\/ \.]{1,21}|[a-zA-Z\-\,0-9\(\)\#\/ \.]{25})(.{0,9}){6}
```

Comment: Or split it in a group of 1 to 21 characters and an optional group of 4 characters: `^([a-zA-Z\-\,0-9\(\)\#\/ \.]{1,21}([a-zA-Z\-\,0-9\(\)\#\/ \.]{4})?)(.{0,9}){6}` at the cost of having a second capture group with the last 4 characters if applicable.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos That will match groups 22-24 characters as well; it's equivalent to `…{1,25}`, which OP stated didn't work. In truth I think the real problem is that the pattern is just poorly defined (how is it supposed to know where to split the last 0 - 54 characters into 6 groups?) but without further information this is the best answer I can give.

Comment: Yes, you are right; the first could match a 19 long string and the second on a 4 long string making it match on a string with length 23.
When I see this question it pops to my mind: Not every problem is suitable to solve with a regular expression.

Comment: ***Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*** — Jamie Zawinski